# Unity 5 How to fire a bullet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on this code for a while and I just cant seem to figure it out. When I click in the game instead of going to the mouse posistion it throws my bullets far away usually from anywhere to 100 to 300.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour {

     public GameObject Player;
     public GameObject Bullet;

     void Update() 
     {
          bool Shot = false;
          if(Input.GetMouseDown(0) && Shot == false)
          {
             Shot = true;
          }

          if (Shot == true)
          { 
            float x = Player.transform.position.x;
            float z = Player.transform.position.z;
            Instantiate(Bullet, new Vector3(x, 0.5f, z)), Quaternion.identity);
            x = Input.mousePosition.x;
            z = Input.mousePosition.z;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please remove "thank you"/"new here" text from your post (all no-code text so far) and replace with explanation what you tried and how it did not work.

Comment: what happens when you actually step through your own code..? are you even using the debugger..? and I normally fire a bullet by pulling the trigger of my `PX4-Storm` please edit the title as well

Comment: Yes but it usually makes my bullets x equall to three hundred

Comment: Hi user, although a good beginner question, it's simply not possible to answer it on this site.  Please (A) create a real nickname (B) come back and ask a specific question when you have a clear specific code question, good luck!  PS search for literally 100s of tutoriais and QA on this try answers.unity3d

Comment: Look, you're basically using the "SCREEN" (!) position rather than converting that to world position.  Google 100s of examples .. http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/514615/view.html hope it helps

Comment: Hi @MethodMan - lol good one.  you know a debugger etc. wouldn't help here: the code is "working" but there's a logical flaw.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make much sense for me; You just instantiate a Gameobject at the last mouse position (which is on you screen, not in the 3D world) and you don't apply any force to it. Please take a look at [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cod-modern-warfare-style-gun-script-update-08-07-2015.52651/) thread (you probably want to use the Gun_Physical script).